# Is it possible to catch a bus (or a jeep) from Bar Funivia to Torre del Filosofo (Etna)?

Tags: italy, buses, sicily, self-guided

I am wondering if it's possible to get a jeep/bus from Bar Funivia to Torre del Filosofo if you are not booking a private tour?

It looks like this is the fastest way to reach Torre del Filosofo, but I cannot find any information how the transportation looks like there.

The first post in [this thread](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g187886-i343-k4769862-Etna_Cable_Car_and_4x4_tickets-Sicily.html) suggests that bus tickets could be purchased at the same place as the cable car tickets. I cannot find any other website confirming that however.